# Assigning innerHTML to elements using $().each via AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This page of my app is a dashboard which consists of `div`'s acting as 'panels', like so

```
<div class='panel' id='usersPanel' data-request='users'>
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <p class='panel-contents'>Will be filled with AJAX results</p>
</div>
```

On page load, they're populated via AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel').each(function(index, value) {
        $.get('/panel', {'content': $(this).attr('data-request')}, function(data) {
            $(this).find('.panel-contents').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

The request is sent fine. The response is OK. But I can't seem to write it into `.panel-contents`. Am I missing something?

Comment: out of curiousity, try doing console.log($(this) ) in the return function.

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @KevinB He said the response was okay. He just cannot replace the html.

Comment: And we're all saying the same thing. within the scope of the returned function, 'this' has changed.

Comment: @AndrewIce Right, exactly. `this` isn't the element node, it's the JQXHR and therefore $(this) won't work.

Comment: That's not the point. inside the returned function, this refers to something different.

Comment: I understand the concept of this thank you.

Comment: Yep. `this` is the request, not the object. Dammit, I spent a day trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your success function. When that executes this equates to something different try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel').each(function(index, value) {
        var panel = this;
        $.get('/panel', {'content': $(this).attr('data-request')}, function(data) {
            $(panel).find('.panel-contents').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: He said the response was okay.  He just cannot replace the html.

Comment: Yes, and I believe he can't replace the html because 'this' within the success function is not the same thing as the 'this' within the success function. The scope is different.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get `this` inside the `$.get` success listener - cache `this` beforehand like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel').each(function(index, value) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.get('/panel', {'content': $(this).attr('data-request')}, function(data) {
            $this.find('.panel-contents').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: :D why the downvote??

Comment: obvious dupe, answer already covered in dupe

Comment: okay, but downvoting *is* not necessary for *that*! (of course, I am not assuming you did it)

Comment: i mean, downvoting/upvoting is never *necessary*

Comment: yeah, sure it is not